# Does Windows use Bluetooth Authenticated pairing with encryption automatically?

Tags: windows, bluetooth

Does Windows use Bluetooth Authenticated pairing with encryption automatically when you connect Bluetooth devices like earbuds to it? Is that Level 4? If it's not automatic, how do I get Windows to do that?

Is there any way to prevent other people from seeing and/or connecting to your Bluetooth devices like earbuds? And only for your phone/laptop to be connected to it?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration of the Bluetooth encryption key size
After being familiar with the available policy settings and the possible values, it’s time to take a look at the steps for configuring the Bluetooth encryption key size policy setting. The nine steps below walk through the configuration of a new custom device configuration profile that includes the required OMA-URI and its value. The wizard style of configuring makes sure that the device configuration profile will be assigned to the selected users and/or devices.

Open the Microsoft Endpoint Manager admin center portal navigate to Devices > Windows > Configuration profiles to open the Windows | Configuration profiles blade
On the Windows | Configuration profiles blade, click Create profile to open the Create a profile page
On the Create a profile page, provide the following information and click Create to open the Custom wizard
Platform: Windows 10 and later
Profile type: Custom
On the Basics page, provide the following information and click Next
Name: Provide a valid name for the custom device configuration profile
Description: (Optional) Provide a valid description for the custom device configuration profile
On the Configuration settings page, click Add to open the Add Row page. On the Add Row page, provide the following information and click Add (and click Next back on the Configuration settings page)
Name: Provide a valid name for the OMA-URI setting
Description: (Optional) Provide a valid description for the OMA-URI setting
Figure 2: Add custom configuration
OMA-URI: ./Vendor/MSFT/Policy/Config/Bluetooth/SetMinimumEncryptionKeySize
Data type: Select Integer
Value: 7
On the Scope tags page, configure the applicable scopes and click Next
On the Assignments page, configure the assignment and click Next
On the Applicability rules page, configure the applicability rules (think about the existence of this setting for only the Business, Enterprise and Education edition and the existence of this setting for only the 2004 version and later) and click Next
On the Review + create page, verify the configuration and click Create
Result of the Bluetooth encryption configuration
Let’s end this post by showing the result of the Bluetooth encryption configuration. This time I’ll do that by simply looking at the Event Viewer and the MDM Diagnostic Report and relating the information seen at both locations. In both overviews the following corresponding information is seen of the successfully applied configuration.

Policy setting: SetMinimumEncryptionKeySize
Policy area: Bluetooth
Policy value: 7
Policy scope: Device
Policy ID: 5C71E17A-2715-47C6-B338-4EE-07C445339

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. Include the relevant parts of the link in your answer here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).